# Simple backend validation error | !preg_match

Tags: php

I am trying to create add a very simple name regex test to my backend validation but I keep receiving an error. From my understanding there should be no issue with this and maybe I'm just tired but I could need another set of eyes on it.

The file is connected with use of a fetch call.

```
$nameRegex = '#/^[A-Za-z]+$/';

if(!preg_match($nameRegex, $_POST['user_first_name'])){
    _res(400, ['Info' => 'Name flaw']);
    exit();
}
```

Following error received is:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

so I would assume that it would be a very simple mistake but I can't seem to locate the error.

Comment: That error is client side, no?

Comment: More info is needed with the question.. is there a POST AJAX requesting sending to this and expecting JSON back? Is `_res` a function your wrote? If so what does it return?

Comment: @user3783243 Yes, there is. The res function is one I wrote myself. Error outputs is being displayed in the console in a JSON format. It works for the other validation parts where I for instance check the length of a password or so.

Comment: What are you submitting and what is the server response on this request?

Comment: Yes, the issue is not related to that. It's most likely a simple syntax error.

Comment: There is no issue with what you posted. You need to provide more data.